# React Native CLI project: How to fix hot reload when using react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I´m using [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) in a React Native CLI project and this [breaks](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10991) the hot reload.

Comment: What is the problem? What is not working? By your question, looks like you already solved the problem?

Comment: @Vencovsky I was just editing out the question since I found it to be better to split it into a separate post. You just beat me before explaing that part.

Comment: I understand what you are doing, but you are doing it wrong. You added the question and answer in the question. It should be separated. The code for the answer should be in the answer.

Comment: @Vencovsk Moved the answer like you suggested. Seems ok now, but let me know if there is anything else, my first question here so still a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this I've found that I need to have a class based root component since hot reload does not support functional root components. I've made this work by wrapping the navigation components in a class based component like this:

```
class NavigationWrapper extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return <NavigationWrapper />;
};
```