# Arrow function logic in React Native CLI project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, arrow-functions

I created a new React Native CLI project and was thinking to convert the App component to a class based component to fix a [hot reload issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10991) when using react-navigation.

But I don't understand the logic with these two arrow functions, and how to convert it:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return <NavigationWrapper />;
};
```

Update: the arrow question was answered, though it didn´t help for the hot reload issue (a glitch in my logic there). See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60511183/react-native-cli-project-how-to-fix-hot-reload-when-using-react-navigation?noredirect=1#comment107050205_60511183) for a solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, be very careful when reading this code. It looks like two arrow functions, but actually the second 'arrow function' is the type annotation of `App`. So it's the same as this:

```
const App: (() => React$Node) = () => {
  return <NavigationWrapper />;
};
```

or even clearer:

```
const App = (): React$Node => {
  return <NavigationWrapper />;
};
```

Then, remember that arrow functions are just like regular functions, so this can be written like so:

```
function App(): React$Node {
  return <NavigationWrapper />;
};
```

So now it becomes pretty clear how this might look:

```
class App {
  render(): React$Node {
    return <NavigationWrapper />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Time for me to dive deeper into the type universe. The class example works except that I had to remove the public keyword.

Comment: Oh right, `render` wouldn't be public. Don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem!